# Notify completion of argo workflow

Tags: event-handling, argo-workflows, argo-events

I have a use case where I am triggering argo workflow from a python application. However, I need a mechanism from argo workflow that it should notify my python application when the workflow execution is completed. I am already using a pub sub mechansim in my python application. So want my python app to subscribe to a redis queue and take action once workflow publishes a message on this queue informing its completion.
This is the interaction flow I am looking for
Workflow ——-> Redis queue ——> Python app
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

you can use Argo Workflows's ExitHandler:

https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/variables/#exit-handler

https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/exit-handlers.yaml